# If i type Delhi-Manali in textbox1 then on Button Click event textbox2.text="Delhi" & textbox3.text="Manali" using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i type in textbox1

textbox1.text="Delhi-manali"

Then on button click event

textbox2.text="Delhi"

Textbox3.text="Manali"

using vb.net

If i type Delhi-Manali in textbox1 then on Button Click event textbox2.text="Delhi" & textbox3.text="Manali"

Comment: Can you give us more detail as to what you want? Are those words going to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using the [String.Split Method (Char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

something like

```
textbox2.text = textbox1.text.Split("-"C)(0)
textbox3.text = textbox1.text.Split("-"C)(1)
```